# vb Script for data entry validation in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for vb script for excel for the condition.

If a value is present in B1 cell it needs to promt to enter a value in A1 also.

Basically value should be present in both the cell A1&B1 for the entire column same needs to be applied.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way that you phrase your question gives the impression that you are trying to use Stack Overflow as a code-writing service. If so, you have mistaken the nature of the site. Taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [ask] might help. If you want help in programming, please show your best efforts. If you don't know where to begin, I suggest that you look into using the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event

Comment: It also isn't clear why VBA is required here. You can use ordinary data validation that won't allow you to enter something in B1 unless there is already something in A1

Comment: I have tried the data validation, But i didnt get the concept or the formula

Answer (score 0):

You can make your users to fill the cell in column A first. Therefore add a data validation to the whole column B with following criteria:

- Allow: Custom
- Uncheck "Ignore blank cells"
- Formula: `=A1<>""`
- Error Alert Message: "Please fill column A value first!"

If now A1 is empty while you enter a value in B1 it forces you to fill A1 first.

Comment: I need to apply the same condition for the entire column A & B

Comment: @sarvanakumar do **exactly** as I wrote! Just select column B and perform the steps above. It will adjust the formula automatically.